# Spotify oEmbed support for short link

Tags: spotify, oembed

Does Spotify oEmbed support short spoti.fy links?

It seems no (e.g. https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/?url=http://spoti.fi/WpbeyP)... but it would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

We've added this feature request to our backlog.